# Why did I punt this baby like a football?

Tags: mighty-switch-force-2

While going through level 2 I noticed a baby. It seems optional since once I rescued the 5 girls as standard the big robot comes to pick you up, but I went further and went to rescue the baby...which Patty promptly kicked off-screen.

What are the babies for? They seem to be optional objectives, but do I get anything for <del>punting</del> saving<sup>?</sup> them? Is there a baby to kick in every level? I found them in levels one and two.

Comment: Another interesting question title from Arqade...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Babies are hidden in different areas throughout the game.  Finding and punting (saving) all of them will unlock Gym Clothes Patty.

There seems to be 1 baby in each level (1-16).  If you would like a video walkthrough, see [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WCGZEueZ7Ug).  The description has time links for each level so it should make it easier to use.